# display the terms of a product attribute in a specific page

Tags: woocommerce, plugins, customization

Can I display all the terms of a woocommerce product attribute in a specific page (even empty terms) and in front of each term the number of products linked with it?

Example:

Attribute A

Term 1 (2)
Term 2 (1)
Term 3 (0)
Term 4 (2)
Term 5 (1)
Term 6 (0)

Regards

I like to have a short code, a small php code or even a plugin

Comment: https://woocommerce.com/document/display-product-attribute-archive-links/

Comment: I did not find what I am looking for in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

**Usage example** `[listtaxonomyterms attribute="pa_color"]`

```
add_shortcode('listtaxonomyterms', 'list_taxonomy_terms');
function list_taxonomy_terms($attr) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'attribute' => '', // example pa_color 
    ), $attr );

    if(!$args['attribute']) return; // If there is no attribute

    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $args['attribute'],
        'hide_empty' => false, // set to true to exclude empty
    ) );
    $attributes = array();
    if($terms):
        foreach($terms as $term):
            /* What we will get from that
            [term_id][name][slug][term_group][term_taxonomy_id][taxonomy][description][parent][count][filter]
            */
            $attributes[] = '<div><span class="name">'.$term->name.'</span><span class="count">'.$term->count.'</span></div>';
        endforeach;
    endif;

    return sprintf('<div class="attribute-list">%s</div>',implode( '', $attributes ));
}
```